# What can One do to Hasten the Repayment of a Loan?

Tags: halacha, borrowing

I have heard stories of the Chofetz Chayim avoiding the streets where debtors of his lived. I have also heard that one is not supposed to pressure a debtor, and I was wondering about the halachic basis and extent of this practice.

If a creditor wants the money back from the debtor, what techniques may he use?

A: May he ask for the loan to be repaid (e.g. "Please, can you repay the 35$ I lent you?")?

B: May he ask **when** the loan will be repaid (e.g. "Do you know when you can repay the loan?")?

C: May he hint at the loan (e.g."So, I have to go pay off a loan right now. It's a good habit, you know.)?

D: May he do nothing to advance to the repayment?

Does the relative amount of the loan (large, small, medium) alter the answer?

Comment: See Devarim 24:10-13

Comment: Probably he should specify a due-date in the loan contract.

Comment: He can ask for a mashkon. But he has to go through bais din.  I believe pressuring a debtor only applies if he believes the debtor has no money. Otherwise he is certainly allowed to pressure him.  @ephraim helfgot

Comment: For someone with a LOT of yiras shomayim: just think that perhaps this person needs the money more than you